# deduplicate messages whil reading from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka log compaction is not working for me.
I used the following code to create the topic :

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper z-3.gfxiq-dev-totalflex-rd.6b5t67.c4.kafka.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:2181,z-1.gfxiq-dev-totalflex-rd.6b5t67.c4.kafka.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:2181,z-2.gfxiq-dev-totalflex-rd.6b5t67.c4.kafka.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:2181  --topic  finals  --replication-factor 1  --partitions 1   --config cleanup.policy=compact   --config min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.001  --config segment.ms=5000
```

It keeps reading the records having the same key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka's log compaction feature is used for cleanup data in the partition, not for deduplication. Let say you insert into the partition A with the following order:

```
[head] (key1, value1) (key2, value2) (key1, value3) [ tail]
```

After compaction phrase at **some future point**, the partition will be:

```
[head] (key2, value2) (key1, value3) [tail]
```

**Before the compaction phrase happens**, any consumer consumes the partition A will see 2 records with the same key `key1`. This mechanism extremely useful for replicate the database (e.g.: MySQL) to some different datastores.

For deduplication, we must know the real reason for duplication to have the correct fix.

1. If that because of multiple inserts with the same key, you must use a separate mechanism for deduplication. You might deduplicate at the source (before writing to Kafka'topics) or sink ( when consuming messages from the topics). That strongly depends on concreted problems. As @criket_007 pointed out, a key-value datastore (e.g.: Redis, Memcache) is a good start for deduplication.
2. If the duplication because of the network error. For instance, you insert `(key1, value1)` into the topic. After brokers received and wrote successfully data to the disk, brokers return the result back to the client. However, the network error happens so clients cannot see the result. Clients think that they haven't delivered yet so they deliver for the second time. Duplication happens. Here is the illustration for this scenario.

[image: duplication because of network error]

So you should use [Idempotent producer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Idempotent+Producer)

[image: idempotent producer]

Answer (score 0):

Compaction is not a key value database; same keys are not immediately updated.

Kafka partitions are stored as segments, a head, compacted segment and an uncompacted tail. By default, segments sizes are 1G. Compaction only happens on "closed segments". Meaning, as you consume across both head, there are no duplicate keys, but you will see them as you read the tail segment.

If you really want to consume something with no duplicate keys, read the topic into a map or KV store